# Linear differential equations, integrating factor

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation:
$$ dr+(2r \cot\theta+\sin 2\theta)d\theta=0$$
I have tried like this:
$$ \frac{dr}{d\theta}+2r\cot\theta=-\sin{2\theta}$$
\begin{align}
I.F. &=e^{\int{2\cot\theta d\theta}}\\
& =e^{-2\log\sin\theta}\\
& =\frac 1{\sin^2\theta}\\
\end{align}
 $$\therefore\frac r{\sin^2\theta}=-\int\frac{\sin 2\theta d\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\\
\implies \frac r{\sin^2\theta}=-2\int{\cot\theta d\theta}\\
\implies \frac r{\sin^2\theta}=2\log\sin\theta+c $$
But in my book the answer is:
$$2r{\sin^2\theta}+{\sin^4\theta}=c$$
Please check out which is correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT...your error is in calculating the IF, which should be $\sin^2\theta$ due to the fact that the integral of $\cot\theta$ is $\log\sin\theta$ not $-\log\sin\theta$

Comment: Ok...I understood my fault..thanks for helping 

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

$$dr+(2r \cot\theta+\sin 2\theta)d\theta=0$$
$$\sin \theta dr+(2r \cos\theta+2\sin^2 \theta\cos\theta )d\theta=0$$
Multiply by $2\sin \theta$:
$$2\sin^2 \theta dr+(4r \cos\theta\sin \theta+4\sin^3 \theta\cos\theta )d\theta=0$$
$$2\sin^2 \theta dr+2r d\sin^2 \theta+ d\sin^4 \theta=0$$
$$2(\sin^2 \theta dr+r d\sin^2 \theta)+ d\sin^4 \theta=0$$
$$2 dr\sin^2 \theta+ d\sin^4 \theta=0$$
Integrate:
$$2 r\sin^2 \theta+ \sin^4 \theta=C$$

Comment: Thanks for solving 

Comment: yw @AnkitaPal it's another approach to your question

Comment: Yup I understood that...it is also a short method for solving

Comment: Thtats greatif it was clear. Yes it shorter and you get rid of the cotan functon lol   @AnkitaPal

Answer (score 0):

You messed up with your multiplication. Multiplying the integral factor to both sides should yield:
$$\dfrac{d}{d\theta}\left(\dfrac{r}{\sin^2\theta}\right)=\left(\dfrac{1}{\sin\theta}\right)^2\dfrac{dr}{d\theta}+2\cot\theta\left(\dfrac{1}{\sin\theta}\right)^2 r=-\sin2\theta\left(\dfrac{1}{\sin\theta}\right)^2=-2\cot\theta$$
and so
$$\dfrac{r}{\sin^2\theta}=-2\int\cot\theta d\theta=-2\log(\sin\theta)+C$$

Comment: But I think integration of cot theta,there will be an extra negative sign for which 2log(sin theta) will be positive

Comment: @AnkitaPal Substitute $u=\sin\theta$. Then, $du=\cos\theta d\theta$, and so $$\int\cot\theta d\theta=\int\dfrac{1}{\sin\theta}(\cos\theta d\theta)=\int\dfrac{1}{u}du=\log u=\log(\sin\theta) $$

Comment: Ok..but can you bring the book's answer??

Comment: @AnkitaPal You miscalculated the integral factor also. Try doing it again.

Comment: I understood my fault...thanks for helping 